# Extracting collocation words from a Lucene Index

Tags: solr, lucene, text-analysis

I have an index of documents stored inside Lucene. I need to extract all collocation words with their frequency from the index. I know there are various algorithms to detect collocations inside a given document, but I don't know of any exiting library that can work with Lucene specifically for this task. Does anyone know any library?

I know how to extract just bi-grams from the lucene index, but not all bi-grams are of course collocation words.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Shingles](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory) which will generate all the n-grams. Then, use facets to get those ngrams back with counts? Or term analysis from admin section.